# microsoft bot framework and luis

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding

I want to create an bot which has to prompt the user for text. if the information provided by the user is general and not specific. for ex:
if we ask the bot : how many alphabets is in the language?
  then the bot should ask : in what language?
How to achieve this?

Comment: This is much too broad. Please read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

To follow along with the example you provided:

1. Create an LUIS intent named, for example, "Determine Language Alphabet"
2. Train the intent using a phrase such as "How many alphabets are in [language]", where [language] is a word like English or Japanese that you've wrapped in an entity name "language"
3. In your code, take the Luis Result and try to find a "language" entity. If it's not found, prompt the user to enter a language/repeat the query with a language

This process will help you get started with understanding how Luis intents and entities can be used to help you better interact with users.

[Using Node JS and LUIS](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/Node/intelligence-LUIS)

[Using .NET and LUIS](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/intelligence-LUIS)